# How to add a reply-to and a from-name header with SendGrid php library

Tags: php, sendgrid

This might be a silly question, but I've looked [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html), [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html) and [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/SMTP_API_Header_Examples/php.html),
and there is no mentioning whatsoever about those simple functionality.

Can I user the addHeader method for this cause?.

Thanks in advance for any help!.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without more info about how you're actually sending the email (web?, smtp?, libraries?, etc), it's hard to give you a concise answer.  That said, one of these three options should work:

**1) If you're sending over HTTP with the web API**

You can actually just add two extra parameters to your POST body, `fromname` and `replyto`, and send them along with the normal `to`, `from`, `subject`, etc.

Docs here: http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html

**2) If you're sending over SMTP with the PHP library**

The PHP helper library ([found here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)) has two helper methods, `setReplyTo` and `setFromName` to help you with that.

```
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
$mail->addTo('foo@bar.com')->
     setReplyTo('someone.else@example.com')->
     setFromName('John Doe')->
     ...
```

**3) If you're sending with SwiftMailer**

SwiftMailer is a popular SMTP library for PHP.  It has it's own helper methods from Reply to and From name.  You can find more info in the docs (see `setReplyTo` and `setFrom`)

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#the-structure-of-a-message

Comment: Thanks a lot once again!
I do have another issue though.
If the message is send to multiple recipients(addTo in a foreach loop), do I need to set the replyTo, and the fromName per each recipient individually, or just once at the end.
And also, why when I try to add a bcc for each mail t hat is sent out by SendGrid for testing purposes, the entire list of me recipients gets disclosed

Comment: There's a lot of questions in your comment.  Mind contacting our support team (http://support.sendgrid.com) or opening up a new question?